# Parsing JSON post requests in Node.js with Express 4

Tags: json, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to write a simple Express applicaiton that recieves JSON in a Post request.  Here is what I have so far on the server:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/acceptContacts', function(req, res) {
    'use strict';
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.body.hello);
    res.send(200);
});

app.listen(8080);
```

And here is what I have on the client in the browser:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/acceptContacts?Content-Type=application/json');
var obj = {hello:'world'};
req.send(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

However, I recieve the following output on the server's console:

```
{}
undefined
```

Can anyone suggest the cause?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It will work if you use `setRequestHeader`:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/acceptContacts');
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
var obj = {hello:'world'};
req.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: What if you don't control the client? If the client is not setting this header, but I know it is posting a JSON body, is there any way I can access it?

Comment: Yes. It should work without the `setRequestHeader` if you also use `app.use(bodyParser.text());`.